# Why is resize2fs misreading the number of blocks in my partition?

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems

I'm trying to shrink a partition to match the size of another partition on another drive.  I heard that I first have to shrink the filesystem to match.  I am trying to do this with `resize2fs`, but if I use the values in

```
cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

 202        0  178257920 xvda
 202        1  178249871 xvda1
 202       32   47185920 xvdc
 202       33   47184896 xvdc1
```

like this

```
ubuntu@asdf:~$ sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1 47184896
```

I get

```
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
The containing partition (or device) is only 44562467 (4k) blocks.
You requested a new size of 47184896 blocks.
```

I have a simliar problem when using `parted`.

```
$ sudo parted /dev/xvda
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/xvda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) resizepart 1 94371839
Error: The location 94371839 is outside of the device /dev/xvda.
```

If I try to do `resizepart 1 94371839` for '/dev/xvda1' in `parted` I get `Error: The location 94371839 is outside of the device /dev/xvda1.` when it's clearly within the block range of the device as shown with

```
sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/xvda: 170 GiB, 182536110080 bytes, 356515840 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/xvda1 *    16065 356515806 356499742  170G 83 Linux
```

This is driving me nuts.  How do I get the proper values for the filesystem size and partition size to use with `resize2fs` and `parted`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`resize2fs` doesn't misread the number of blocks. It is just using 4k blocks while `/proc/partitions` is reporting 1k blocks.

356499742 x 512B sectors = 178249871 x 1K blocks = 44562467 x 4K blocks

With `parted`, you can to configure the unit you want to use. It seems `parted` uses MB by default, so you are asking to resize a 170GB partition to 94TB, which it rightly refuses.

Here is one way to do it correctly:

```
parted /dev/sdb
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sdb
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) help unit                                                        
  unit UNIT                                set the default unit to UNIT

    UNIT is one of: s, B, kB, MB, GB, TB, compact, cyl, chs, %, kiB, MiB,
        GiB, TiB
(parted) unit kiB                                                         
(parted) print                                                            
Model: ATA VBOX HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 524288kiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start      End        Size       Type     File system  Flags
 1      1024kiB    205824kiB  204800kiB  primary  ext3
 2      205824kiB  410624kiB  204800kiB  primary  ext3
(parted) resizepart 1 200000                                              
Warning: Shrinking a partition can cause data loss, are you sure you want to
continue?
Yes/No? Yes                                                               
(parted) print                                                            
Model: ATA VBOX HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 524288kiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start      End        Size       Type     File system  Flags
 1      1024kiB    200000kiB  198977kiB  primary  ext3
 2      205824kiB  410624kiB  204800kiB  primary  ext3
```

Comment: Okay, so what should I be using to find the size without having to bust out my calculator?

Comment: Well, each of the commands you use have their own good reason to use a different unit, 4k, 1k or 512b. I'm afraid you'll have to bust out your calculator.

Comment: See my edit, I'm assuming the same thing is happening with `parted`?

Comment: The issue is less clear with resizepart. You should copy/paste the full command and response to be sure.

Comment: There's really not much more to it, I edited my question to make it clearer

Comment: Here's the description for the specific command within `parted` -
 https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/parted.html#resizepart
Note the reference to `resize2fs`

Comment: So have you shrink your file system first?

Comment: Yes I managed to do that.  I shrank it to the size of the smaller disk's partition.